# Separating bullet in motion from mouse clicked

Tags: java, 2d

Please how can I make already shot bullet to be separated from my mouseclicked horizontal position, so that bullets in motion dont't move when I click the mouse.
And also I need to create a way to move unto the next level when all the shapes are shot now I cannot do.

```
class CreateImage extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
       ArrayList<fallShape> rect= new ArrayList<fallShape>();
        ArrayList<fallShape1> rect1= new ArrayList<fallShape1>();
         ArrayList<fallShape2> rect2= new ArrayList<fallShape2>();
       ArrayList<Integer> by_poss = new ArrayList<>();

       int x_pos=mousework.Width/2;
       int y_pos=mousework.Height-50;
       int bx_pos=mousework.Width/2;
       int by_pos=mousework.Height;
       int y_speed=-15;
       int x_speed=(int)Math.random()*10+1;
       boolean clicked;
       int yyy=420;
       int score=0;
       int scoreb=10;
       //createImage constructor
     public CreateImage(){
         super(true);
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      rect.add(new fallShape(12,12,rect));
      }
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      rect1.add(new fallShape1(12,12,rect1));
     }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
          rect2.add(new fallShape2(12,12,rect2));
     }
    if(rect.isEmpty()==true&&rect1.isEmpty()==true&&rect2.isEmpty()==true){
           int yyy=420;
         }
     Toolkit picx=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    gunMage=picx.getImage("gunner.jpg");
    gunMage=gunMage.getScaledInstance(200,-1,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
      Toolkit pic=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      pixMage=pic.getImage("ballfall3.jpg");
      pixMage=pixMage.getScaledInstance(200,-1,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
      addMouseListener(this);
       addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
       public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
           x_pos=e.getX()-5;
          }
       });
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
       if(e.getButton()==1){
          by_poss.add(mousework.Height);
          bx_pos=e.getX();
      }


    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}


    //updating graphics
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
           super.paintComponent(g);
         g.drawImage(pixMage,0,0,Width,Height,null);
           Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
           g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
       g.drawImage(gunMage,x_pos,y_pos,10,20,null);
       g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           Rectangle2D.Float bullet=new Rectangle2D.Float(bx_pos,by_pos,3,10);

             for(int i = 0; i < by_poss.size(); i++){
             by_poss.set(i, by_poss.get(i)+y_speed); //move the bullet
              if(by_poss.get(i)>=mousework.Height){
                   by_poss.clear();
               }
             bullet=new Rectangle2D.Float(bx_pos,by_poss.get(i),3,10);


            g2.fill(bullet);
            //g2.draw(bullet);
       }

       g2.setColor(Color.RED);
       for(fallShape2 b: rect2){
           b.move();
           g2.fill(b);
        if(b.intersects(bullet)&& bullet.y<mousework.Height){

           for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

            rect2.remove(i);
           click.play();
           score+=scoreb;
          }
        }

    }
       for(fallShape1 b: rect1){
             b.move();
            g2.fill(b);
           if(b.intersects(bullet)&& bullet.y<mousework.Height){

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
               rect1.removeRange(i,i);
               click.play();
               score+=scoreb;
             }


           }

        }

        for(fallShape b: rect){
            b.move();
            g2.fill(b);
          if(b.intersects(bullet)&& bullet.y<mousework.Height){
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
              rect.remove(i);
              click.play();
              score+=scoreb;
            }
            }

         }


         g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         g2.setFont(new Font("CALIFORNIAN FB",Font.BOLD,15));
          g2.drawString((score+""),265,10);

            //boolean onStroke;
      //g2.hit(bullet,rect,onStroke);
     if(yyy==420){
          close();
          new room().setVisible(true);

      }
    }
public void close(){
  WindowEvent closy=new WindowEvent(new mousework2(),WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(closy);
 }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add more disription and comments and formatation in the future :)

If i understood you rigth, your problem is that if you click the mouse again, all bullets are moved to the same x position and are than flying in one line.
To me the code looks like you allways update the complete picture.
So you need xposition attribute for every bullet.
You have to add an array similar to ArrayList by_poss. So add this

```
ArrayList<Integer> bx_pos_Array = new ArrayList<>();
```

after

```
ArrayList<fallShape> rect= new ArrayList<fallShape>();
ArrayList<fallShape1> rect1= new ArrayList<fallShape1>();
ArrayList<fallShape2> rect2= new ArrayList<fallShape2>();
ArrayList<Integer> by_poss = new ArrayList<>();
```

and set it by the creation of the bullet.
So change

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
       if(e.getButton()==1){
          by_poss.add(mousework.Height);
          bx_pos=e.getX();
      }


    }
```

to

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
           if(e.getButton()==1){
              by_poss.add(mousework.Height);
              bx_pos=e.getX();
              bx_pos_Array.add(bx_pos);  //add this line
          }


        }
```

and change

```
for(int i = 0; i < by_poss.size(); i++){
             by_poss.set(i, by_poss.get(i)+y_speed); //move the bullet
              if(by_poss.get(i)>=mousework.Height){
                   by_poss.clear();
               }
             bullet=new Rectangle2D.Float(bx_pos,by_poss.get(i),3,10);


            g2.fill(bullet);
            //g2.draw(bullet);
       }
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < by_poss.size(); i++){
             by_poss.set(i, by_poss.get(i)+y_speed); //move the bullet
              if(by_poss.get(i)>=mousework.Height){
                   by_poss.clear();
               }
             bullet=new Rectangle2D.Float(bx_pos_Array.get(i),by_poss.get(i),3,10);  //this line (the first argument)changed


            g2.fill(bullet);
            //g2.draw(bullet);
       }
```

for drowing each bullet with its own xpos

greetings Jones

Comment: And please I am also having a problem with my shooting sometimes when a bullet intersects a certain shape another shape is removed and not the one it intersects.......I would be grateful if you can help me with that